# Clicking through an undefined number of dialog boxes

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

Currently I am using ProtractorJS to access a page that has an unspecified number of popup dialog boxes that are not crucial to the operation of the webpage, but block further interaction with it.

For example, when I open the login screen several (but of unknown quantity) pop-ups appear, and one after another (they are not present at the same time).  I am currently handling this in a sloppy way (I see if the object is present and click the existing button to terminate it) and I believe their has to be a better way of handling this...  Essentially, I would like to "loop" through these actions till they are finished, in a promise like manner if possible.

Also, as a caveat, I would like to be able to handle messages that randomly should appear, without disrupting the flow of my tests.  I understand the latter maybe a little to good to be true,  but I figured I would ask.

Comment: Can these popups be closed with, say, pushing escape? I mean, the logic behind closing the popup is the same across all of the possible popups you can get?

Comment: Sorry @alecxe, cant escape out, thanks for the input though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
boolean popupFound=true;
while (popupFound) {
    try {
        // You should temporarily lower implicit wait to avoid slowing things down
        driver.setImplicitWait(6);
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); // select ok or cancel
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
        // Not needed so exit; assumes no delay between popups
        popupFound = false;
    } finally {
        driver.setImplicitWait(60); // Or whatever you had it set at originally
    }
}
```

Better make sure that implicit wait is only as large as it needs to be.

Comment: So, I will try this on Monday @Mike and give it an answer (sorry about the wait)...  But I am skeptical of the speed in which this will execute, I considered doing something like this for another similar project.  I fear I will have an issue with promises resolving at odd intervals while the loop is still, well, looping (I assume this is what the wait is for).  But I will give it a shot, Thanks.

Comment: The implicit wait is how long selenium waits for an event to occur.  So the above waits 6 seconds for driver.switchTo().alert().accept() to succeed with a default retry interval of less than a second.  If at the end of 6 seconds the command hasn't succeeded it throws the exception. You have to set implicit wait time to what works for your application.  Image if there were no alerts? You don't want to wait too long before moving on.which is why I dropped the implicit wait time.

Comment: @jsNoob Did this answer work for you? If so how about accepting it? I am trying to get to 500 reputation points.  :-)